# How to create MSI or exe in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have created one GUI app in python 3.6 and which is working fine on my system. Now i want to give the same GUI application to my friend to install it on there own machine.
The GUI i have created referring to some images.

My requirement is once anyone can install it and can see all the images which i have used in application.
I want to create the shortcut with the icon on desktop like the other apps which we install.

I have tried pytoexe,pyinstaller etc but it doesn't work for python 3.6

Please help me to create the setup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To create an EXE-File try pyinstaller or cx_freeze. They both work for python3.6.

Comment: Added example line for PyInstaller.

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller works for Python 3.6. If you are using Windows, just open the command prompt (with admin rights) change your directory to where you want the new package to be created. Then use the correct command line from the docs:

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html#running-pyinstaller-with-python-optimizations

Within the dist folder you will see the *.exe file that will run your program. (You may also create the whole thing as a single file using the --onefile option)

Here is an example usage:

```
pyinstaller -w --name=NameYourProgram --clean "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\source_code_file.py"
```